# How can I make flash remember my low quality setting?

Tags: firefox, flash, web, greasemonkey

I play a web browser game but I have a very old laptop. The graphics are too heavy on my resources and setting the quality to low improves performance. But it keeps resetting to high every time I log in.

I have tried 2 Greasemonkey scripts like [this](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/38994) and [this](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/63268) to no avail. I found that the game uses an iframe to load the game so I can't access the object or embed tags, maybe that's why the scripts do not work. Any ideas?